# Prolog write the is_progression predicate to check that the sequence of elements of a numerical list is a geometric progression

Tags: prolog

Write the is_progression predicate to check that the sequence of elements
of a numerical list is a geometric progression.

Comment: Is this homework? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a geometric progression is a series of non-zero numbers, where each term after the first is the result of multiplying the previous by some fixed value (their common ration), correct? SO

`1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...` is a geometric progression where the common ratio is 2.

We can define that in Prolog easily:

```
progression( X , _ , X ) .
progression( X , R , N ) :- progression1(X,R,N) .

progression1( X , R , N ) :- N  is X*R .
progression1( X , R , N ) :- X1 is X*R , progression1(X1,R,N) .
```

This successively yields the desired geometric progression.

To test whether a given list represents a geometric progression then, is a matter of traversing the list and testing the ratio between adjacent elements of the list.

Something like this:

```
progression( [A,B|Cs] , R ) :-  % A geometric progression has to have a least to values
    number(A),                  % - both of which must be numeric
    number(B),                  %
    R is B / A ,                % - compute the expected ratio
    progression_( [B|Cs] , R )  % - invoke the helper, discarding the 1st element
    .                           % Easy!

progression_( []       , _ ) .  % is the source list exhausted? If so, we're done.
progression_( [_]      , _ ) .  % is the source list of length 1? If so, we're done.
progression_( [A,B|Cs] , R ) :- % otherwise...
    B =:= A * R ,               % - if the current item (B)  is identical to the previous item times the ratio
    progression_([B|Cs], R ) .  % - discard the previous item and recurse down.
```

If you don't care what the common ratio might be, you can simplify things down to:

```
progression( [A,B|Cs] ) :- progression1( [A,B|Cs] ) .

progression1( []         ) .
progression1( [_]        ) .
progression1( [_,_]      ) .
progression1( [A,B,C|Ds] ) :-
    number(A),
    number(B),
    number(C),
    B / A =:= C / B ,
    progression1( [B,C|Ds] )
    .
```

Note that these solutions treat a sequence of two numbers, say `[1, 2]` as being a [very short] geometric progression.